# How to append unique numbers to new duplicated post titles/urls?

Tags: post-duplication

As of now if you create two (2) posts with the same title you get the following:

`domain.com/test/
domain.com/test-2/`

If you create a third post, you then get another url like:

`domain.com/test-3/`

I am working on a directory, so the odds of someone having the same name is pretty good; therefore I want to append a custom url string to the end of the duplicated name - not just a 1 digit number.

Is there a way for me to add a custom 4-5 digit string at the end of a duplicate post/page/listing? So that it reads:

`domain.com/test/
domain.com/test-#####/ < the random string`

thanks!

Comment: you can use post id on url `domain.com/145/test-post` or `domain.com/test-post-145` that would always give you unique url. I like the first one. You can do it with CPT, on post using permalink. but I never found a solution to add it on page though.

Comment: Is there a way to randomize the numbers that append to the duplicates?

Comment: I don't know what CPT is, is it a plugin? how do I get it so that the post id is within the url? I have my permalinks setup as follows: /%post_id%/%postname%/

Answer (score 2):

Filter `wp_unique_post_slug`. Make sure to add the callback with `6` as last argument to get the original slug. Then create a new unique slug as you need it, you get a lot of context information.

```
add_filter(
    'wp_unique_post_slug',
    function (
        $slug,
        $post_ID,
        $post_status,
        $post_type,
        $post_parent,
        $original_slug
    )
{
    // create a new unique slug based on $original_slug
    return $slug;
}, 10, 6 );
```